# Java stack - ORM vs Database Scalability

Tags: java, orm, scalability, sharding

We are currently working on the design of web project and we have to use java stack for it.

For the start we could use single database (PostgreSQL in our case) considering limited load. In this case ORM like Hibernate would be a good decision, because as [we know](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) object/relational problem is always one of the most time and cost consuming one. This is the whole reason to use ORM tools - cheap, saves much time.

But the problem with this, is that we expecting sharding and master/slave (read/write) replication in database layer later on, which is a real problem for ORM ( at least as far as I know).

Please correct me if I'm wrong and there is a good ORM tool for java stack that we could use.

I know there was a project called [Hibernate Shards](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-shards/) which could solve the problem, but it never passed beta version and development of it stopped in year 2007, according to the link.

Using regular Hibernate with distributed level 2 cache, we could use number of nodes

with business logic, but this won't solve the problem with database scalability, and we could still use only one database for the application.

Bottom line: Is there opensource/free ORM suitable for our case(java stack), or should we implement it ourselves, even with considerable costs, in order to provide database scalability and probably other benefits later.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you considering horizontal or vertical sharding?

Comment: Boris, we considering horizontal sharding. Frankly, I'm not aware of the term 'Vertical sharding', do you mean vertical table partitioning?

Comment: Okay, in that case you should be able to use Hibernate's MultiTenant sessionfactory - you can assign a connection source to each database and then select which one to use.

Comment: Im not sure that this is what I'm looking for - this solves multitenancy problem which is usualy a security problem ( clients of your application are so conserned about security of their data so they force application developer to use separate database or schema for them (database in your comment). This would probably work if you want make horizontal partitioning based on tenant id (user id). In this case Hibernate will use cache on per client basis.In our case,sharding(horizontal partitioning) should be done by range, and not by tenant id,which means that cache cant work on per tenant basis.

Answer (score 0):

I have to put in a good word for Java Data Objects, and especially for the implementation at http://www.datanucleus.org Especially if you use annotations and the typesafe query language, it's very easy to get up to speed and do really interesting stuff very quickly.

In addition, JDO is database-agnostic, so if you decide you'd rather use something other than a relational database, the conversion is relatively straightforward. Since it uses a JDBC driver to connect to the database, clustering/sharding solutions that attach at that level should be relatively transparent. (That's completely wishful thinking on my part--I don't know that it's true, but it should be, right?)

I gave myself two or three days with Hibernate and a large book and decided that I was repeating myself way too often and limiting myself to RDB systems. Give it a look and see what you think.

Answer (score -1):

One solution to consider is purchasing a horizontal scalability solution that will take care of all of these problems for you.

Several solutions exist that will allow you to horizontally scale without changes to your application (changes that would be required by techniques like sharding).